# Can I use google Analytics to customise a page dynamically?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a page on my website that has Google Analytics. Can I add javascript code that uses Google Analytics information of the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Real Time Reporting API, however there are latency times and the information is not complete.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3

Comment: Thanks! I dont know how I never stumbled upon that.